# Starting a CSS animation from a different position

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I am building a model of the solar system and I am using CSS animations to animate the planets moving around the sun like so:

```
.earthMini {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  --radius: 1rem;
  top: calc(50% - var(--radius));
  left: calc(50% - var(--radius));
  width: calc(2 * var(--radius));
  height: calc(2 * var(--radius));
  background: url("../../planetTextures/earth.jpg") repeat-x;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  animation: earthOrbit 45s linear infinite, translateBackground 50s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes earthOrbit {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(13rem) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(13rem) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

This is working great, however when the page first loads all of the planets are animating from the same start position:

[image: example]

I am seeking a way to have each planet have a different start position in its orbit.

I have a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-surf-ekpnm?file=/src/systems/sol/solsystem.js) with my full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative `animation-delay` rule to have the animation start further in their initial animation.

you could set this through some arbitrary values in your css, or apply an actual random using javascript.

```
.earthMini {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  --radius: 1rem;
  top: calc(50% - var(--radius));
  left: calc(50% - var(--radius));
  width: calc(2 * var(--radius));
  height: calc(2 * var(--radius));
  background: url("../../planetTextures/earth.jpg") repeat-x;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  animation: earthOrbit 45s linear infinite, translateBackground 50s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: -45s; // <- this will place earth at the point of animation for 45s, 
}
@keyframes earthOrbit {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(13rem) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(13rem) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

[your codepen with some modifications](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-water-db9fu?file=/src/systems/sol/sol-system.css)